# How to loop through these input fields but with each input having their own state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using `Vuetify` to generate text fields and i am v-modelling them to a `textFieldState` but what happens is that every text f-field ends up sharing the same state and what i write in text field 1 leaks into other text fields. How do i make it so that each field preserves it's own state.

```
  <div v-if="threeTextFields">
 <label for="" v-for="textField in textFields" :key="textField">
   <v-text-field :label="textField" :value="textField" v- 
model="textFieldState"></v-text-field>
 </label>
</div>

data(){
return{
textFieldState:"",
textFields: [
   "Account ID",
   "Settings Tolerance",
   "Library Tolerance"
 ],
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following code structure, each item in `textFields` array has two properties `value` and `state`, so bind `value` to value attribute and `state` to `v-model`:

```
data() {
    return {
      textFieldState: "",
      textFields: [{
          value: "Account ID",
          state: ""
        },
        {
          value: "Settings Tolerance",
          state: ""
        },
        {
          value: "Library Tolerance",
          state: ""
        }
      ],
    }
```

```
<div v-if="threeTextFields">
  <label for="" v-for="textField in textFields" :key="textField">
   <v-text-field :label="textField" :value="textField.value" v- 
model="textField.state"></v-text-field>
 </label>
</div>
```